# dpkg dependencies problem

Tags: dpkg

I'm having problem upgrading my Debian 10 Linux machine. After I input the `sudo apt update && upgrade` and all downloaded completed, I ran into dependencies problem that I ought to have fix by `sudo apt --fix-broken install`  but still run into following error:

```
E: Invalid archive signature
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{zstlz4gzxzbz2lzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libpolkit-agent-1-0_0.105-30_amd64.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: error: '/var/cache/apt/archives/libpolkit-agent-1-0_0.105-30_amd64.deb' is not a Debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpolkit-agent-1-0_0.105-30_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpolkit-agent-1-0_0.105-30_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)*****
```

The dependencies will never allow me to install any package on my terminal anymore unless I clear the unpacking dependencies problem. [image]

Comment: Did you run out of disk space at some stage? If you have a fast, unmetered internet connection remove everything in /var/cache/apt/archives and try again. If you don't have a fast connection then remove the libpolkit-agent* files from that directory and try again.

Answer (score 0):

First run:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt reinstall libpolkit-agent
```

If it doesn't work run:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libpolkit-agent.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libpolkit-agent
sudo apt install libpolkit-agent
```

Comment: Thanks this just solved my problem .

Comment: @Adex great! don't forget to accept my answer, please.